# Parse field of json data in Snowflake table insert multiple rows into new Snowflake table

Tags: json, parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a field/column 'reactions' in a Snowflake table 'tbl'. The table contains several columns of data and many records. The 'reactions' field is a json array. The json data may have several reaction objects (denoted by 'name') and lists the 'users' which had the reaction(see example array below). I'd like to parse this field of data into a new table so that each userID of a reaction is it's own record, and contains the reaction 'name', along with some other columns of data from the source table 'tbl'. I've tried to flatten the data and use json parse but I've been unsuccessful in reaching the desired output. Any support or guidance provided would be soo greatly appreciated!

Example of "Reaction" field value containing the json array:

```
[{
    "name": "wave",
    "users": ["UM6G1DGBG", "UUW2KMQF8", "UG47U9K9N", "U01KCT0KJHL", "U7GRE4E9M", "UU1V5U3B4", "U01S7RRG21Y", "U013J1D5NFQ", "U020AS49MFA", "U010F5EDDQV", "U01ETTJHY4F"],
    "count": 11
}, {
    "name": "wave::skin-tone-3",
    "users": ["UUBFUS220"],
    "count": 1
}, {
    "name": "fire",
    "users": ["U01ETTJHY4F"],
    "count": 1
}]
```

Desired output will look something like this:

| OtherData1 | UserID | ReactionName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Attribute1 | UM6G1DGBG | wave |
| Attribute1 | UUW2KMQF8 | wave |
| Attribute1 | UG47U9K9N | wave |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Attribute1 | U01ETTJHY4F | fire |

Answer (score 0):

You can create the results you want with the following

````
with tbl as (select 'foo' other_data, parse_json('[{
    "name": "wave",
    "users": ["UM6G1DGBG", "UUW2KMQF8", "UG47U9K9N", "U01KCT0KJHL", "U7GRE4E9M", "UU1V5U3B4", "U01S7RRG21Y", "U013J1D5NFQ", "U020AS49MFA", "U010F5EDDQV", "U01ETTJHY4F"],
    "count": 11
}, {
    "name": "wave::skin-tone-3",
    "users": ["UUBFUS220"],
    "count": 1
}, {
    "name": "fire",
    "users": ["U01ETTJHY4F"],
    "count": 1
}]') users)

select 
    other_data,  
    user_ids.value,  
    u.value:name,  
    u.value  
from tbl,  
lateral flatten(users) u,  
lateral flatten(u.value:users) user_ids
;



OTHER_DATA  VALUE   U.VALUE:NAME    VALUE
foo "UM6G1DGBG" "wave"  {    "count": 11,    "name": "wave",    "users": [      "UM6G1DGBG",      "UUW2KMQF8",      "UG47U9K9N",      "U01KCT0KJHL",      "U7GRE4E9M",      "UU1V5U3B4",      "U01S7RRG21Y",      "U013J1D5NFQ",      "U020AS49MFA",      "U010F5EDDQV",      "U01ETTJHY4F"    ]  }
foo "UUW2KMQF8" "wave"  {    "count": 11,    "name": "wave",    "users": [      "UM6G1DGBG",      "UUW2KMQF8",      "UG47U9K9N",      "U01KCT0KJHL",      "U7GRE4E9M",      "UU1V5U3B4",      "U01S7RRG21Y",      "U013J1D5NFQ",      "U020AS49MFA",      "U010F5EDDQV",      "U01ETTJHY4F"    ]  }
foo "UG47U9K9N" "wave"  {    "count": 11,    "name": "wave",    "users": [      "UM6G1DGBG",      "UUW2KMQF8",      "UG47U9K9N",      "U01KCT0KJHL",      "U7GRE4E9M",      "UU1V5U3B4",      "U01S7RRG21Y",      "U013J1D5NFQ",      "U020AS49MFA",      "U010F5EDDQV",      "U01ETTJHY4F"    ]  }
foo "U01KCT0KJHL"   "wave"  {    "count": 11,    "name": "wave",    "users": [      "UM6G1DGBG",      "UUW2KMQF8",      "UG47U9K9N",      "U01KCT0KJHL",      "U7GRE4E9M",      "UU1V5U3B4",      "U01S7RRG21Y",      "U013J1D5NFQ",      "U020AS49MFA",      "U010F5EDDQV",      "U01ETTJHY4F"    ]  }
foo "U7GRE4E9M" "wave"  {    "count": 11,    "name": "wave",    "users": [      "UM6G1DGBG",      "UUW2KMQF8",      "UG47U9K9N",      "U01KCT0KJHL",      "U7GRE4E9M",      "UU1V5U3B4",      "U01S7RRG21Y",      "U013J1D5NFQ",      "U020AS49MFA",      "U010F5EDDQV",      "U01ETTJHY4F"    ]  }
foo "UU1V5U3B4" "wave"  {    "count": 11,    "name": "wave",    "users": [      "UM6G1DGBG",      "UUW2KMQF8",      "UG47U9K9N",      "U01KCT0KJHL",      "U7GRE4E9M",      "UU1V5U3B4",      "U01S7RRG21Y",      "U013J1D5NFQ",      "U020AS49MFA",      "U010F5EDDQV",      "U01ETTJHY4F"    ]  }
foo "U01S7RRG21Y"   "wave"  {    "count": 11,    "name": "wave",    "users": [      "UM6G1DGBG",      "UUW2KMQF8",      "UG47U9K9N",      "U01KCT0KJHL",      "U7GRE4E9M",      "UU1V5U3B4",      "U01S7RRG21Y",      "U013J1D5NFQ",      "U020AS49MFA",      "U010F5EDDQV",      "U01ETTJHY4F"    ]  }
foo "U013J1D5NFQ"   "wave"  {    "count": 11,    "name": "wave",    "users": [      "UM6G1DGBG",      "UUW2KMQF8",      "UG47U9K9N",      "U01KCT0KJHL",      "U7GRE4E9M",      "UU1V5U3B4",      "U01S7RRG21Y",      "U013J1D5NFQ",      "U020AS49MFA",      "U010F5EDDQV",      "U01ETTJHY4F"    ]  }
foo "U020AS49MFA"   "wave"  {    "count": 11,    "name": "wave",    "users": [      "UM6G1DGBG",      "UUW2KMQF8",      "UG47U9K9N",      "U01KCT0KJHL",      "U7GRE4E9M",      "UU1V5U3B4",      "U01S7RRG21Y",      "U013J1D5NFQ",      "U020AS49MFA",      "U010F5EDDQV",      "U01ETTJHY4F"    ]  }
foo "U010F5EDDQV"   "wave"  {    "count": 11,    "name": "wave",    "users": [      "UM6G1DGBG",      "UUW2KMQF8",      "UG47U9K9N",      "U01KCT0KJHL",      "U7GRE4E9M",      "UU1V5U3B4",      "U01S7RRG21Y",      "U013J1D5NFQ",      "U020AS49MFA",      "U010F5EDDQV",      "U01ETTJHY4F"    ]  }
foo "U01ETTJHY4F"   "wave"  {    "count": 11,    "name": "wave",    "users": [      "UM6G1DGBG",      "UUW2KMQF8",      "UG47U9K9N",      "U01KCT0KJHL",      "U7GRE4E9M",      "UU1V5U3B4",      "U01S7RRG21Y",      "U013J1D5NFQ",      "U020AS49MFA",      "U010F5EDDQV",      "U01ETTJHY4F"    ]  }
foo "UUBFUS220" "wave::skin-tone-3" {    "count": 1,    "name": "wave::skin-tone-3",    "users": [      "UUBFUS220"    ]  }
foo "U01ETTJHY4F"   "fire"  {    "count": 1,    "name": "fire",    "users": [      "U01ETTJHY4F"    ]  }```

So to create the table do something like `create table flattened_tbl(other_data, user_name, user_data) as select other_data, u.value:name, u.value from tbl, lateral flatten(users) u;`
````

Comment: Hi @Nat Taylor thanks for your response. I believe that would get me a record per name instead of a record per userID (example User ID value "U01ETTJHY4F"). I probably didn't communicate that well enough originally so I've modified the post description with the desired output table to better communicate my goal.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your use case, I think.