# How to parse the following JSON to retrieve the name of the item in snowflake sql?

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```json
 [
  {
    "itemId": "HWKDVCXKU5",
    "name": "A",
    "quantity": 1.000000000000000e+00,
    "storeId": 1.150192000000000e+06,
    "type": "structure"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "FPK81M587X",
    "name": "b",
    "quantity": 1.000000000000000e+00,
    "storeId": 1.150192000000000e+06,
    "type": "structure"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "L04WBQON3C",
    "name": "C",
    "quantity": 2.000000000000000e+00,
    "storeId": 1.150192000000000e+06,
    "type": "structure"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "ULZFPY2UJN",
    "name": "D",
    "quantity": 2.000000000000000e+00,
    "storeId": 1.150192000000000e+06,
    "type": "structure"
  },
```

I want all the names and quantity in 2 column, I don't know how to write query from the same.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68820565/parse-field-of-json-data-in-snowflake-table-insert-multiple-rows-into-new-snowfl .. The manual pages which explain JSON_PARSE https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_json.html and FLATTEN https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html

Comment: Why aren't you storing the data in normalized form in the first place?

Comment: It's already stored in this form, I just have to retrieve the name of the items.
It's just a sample the actual data size is huge.

Comment: _the actual data size is huge_. bad decision storing "data" as json. now you have two problems.

Comment: Storing TB of JSON is not a problem is snowflake, BUT each json block has a limit of 16MB so you really should not ingest large amounts of data as a single array of JSON, really something like NDJSON or CSV JSON with "only one column" should be used, then processing this in SF is a breaze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using a sub-select to "make the data" and then using PARSE_JSON and FLATTEN we get:

```
SELECT 
  f.value:name::text as name,
  f.value:quantity::float as quanitiy
  FROM (
      SELECT PARSE_JSON('[
  {
    "itemId": "HWKDVCXKU5",
    "name": "A",
    "quantity": 1.000000000000000e+00,
    "storeId": 1.150192000000000e+06,
    "type": "structure"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "FPK81M587X",
    "name": "b",
    "quantity": 1.000000000000000e+00,
    "storeId": 1.150192000000000e+06,
    "type": "structure"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "L04WBQON3C",
    "name": "C",
    "quantity": 2.000000000000000e+00,
    "storeId": 1.150192000000000e+06,
    "type": "structure"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "ULZFPY2UJN",
    "name": "D",
    "quantity": 2.000000000000000e+00,
    "storeId": 1.150192000000000e+06,
    "type": "structure"
  }]') as json
       ) j
  ,TABLE(FLATTEN(input=>json)) f;
```

which gives:

| NAME | QUANITIY |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 2 |

another way to see the exact same code but with the JSON moved to a CTE (so it looks like a normal table)

```
WITH data_cte AS (
    SELECT PARSE_JSON('[
  {
    "itemId": "HWKDVCXKU5",
    "name": "A",
    "quantity": 1.000000000000000e+00,
    "storeId": 1.150192000000000e+06,
    "type": "structure"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "FPK81M587X",
    "name": "b",
    "quantity": 1.000000000000000e+00,
    "storeId": 1.150192000000000e+06,
    "type": "structure"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "L04WBQON3C",
    "name": "C",
    "quantity": 2.000000000000000e+00,
    "storeId": 1.150192000000000e+06,
    "type": "structure"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "ULZFPY2UJN",
    "name": "D",
    "quantity": 2.000000000000000e+00,
    "storeId": 1.150192000000000e+06,
    "type": "structure"
  }]') as json
)
SELECT 
  f.value:name::text as name,
  f.value:quantity::float as quanitiy
  FROM data_cte j
  ,TABLE(FLATTEN(input=>json)) f;
```

Comment: Is it going to be faster compared to storing and querying the data as separate rows?

Comment: @SalmanA I read your question to be, is if a) faster to read from external stage into a tmp table, then read the json out of the tmp table into the destination table verse b) read from the external stage with a transform on the json and land the transformed results in one. B) is faster is you are pulling in all data, because external stores a most IO bound so you have cpu spare to do the transform work. BUT I like to load, into a table, and then transform into another table, just so I have copies of the raw data.

Comment: I am just not a fan of storing data as JSON when you have some querying to do on values. Converting JSON to rows on-demand is always going to use CPU and IO (op says there is lots of data). Converting JSON to rows and columns and storing will eliminate this.

Comment: ah, I load all via JSON, so to me it's part of the ELT process where L is COPY in json_raw table, and then I T into natural columns. So I think we are in agreement. But to do the T you have to know how to get the values you want out of the json.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach for your problem:

```
create or replace stage my_json_stage;
PUT file:///Users/athakur/Downloads/Chrome Downloads/test.json @my_json_stage auto_compress=false;

create or replace table test_json
( my_value variant);

copy into test_json from @my_json_stage/test.json
file_format = (type = JSON strip_outer_array = true)
ON_Error = Continue;

select * from test_json;
select $1:name::string, $1:quantity::string from test_json;
```